# How to inject mocks into a class that has 1 constructor with parameters?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

I have the following class (Condensed it to focus on issue instead of showing entire class):

```
@Component
public class ABCDEF {

    private final Helper helper;
    private final URI uri;

    public ABCDEF(Helper helper, @Value("${endpoint.url}") URI uri) {
        this.helper = helper;
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public void b(){
        helper.toString();
    }
}
```

For its test, I am looking to inject the mocks as follows but it is not working. 
The helper comes up as null and I end up having to add a default constructor to be able to throw the URI exception.

Please advice a way around this to be able to properly inject the mocks. Thanks.

```
@RunWith(JUnitMockitoRunner.class)
public class ABCDEFTest {

    @Mock
    private Helper helper;

    @InjectMocks
    private ABCDEF abcdef = new ABCDEF(
            helper,
            new URI("test")
    );

    // adding just to be able to throw Exception
    public ABCDEFTest() throws URISyntaxException {
    }

    @Test
    public void b() {
        abcdef.b();
    }
}
```

Note: Using Mockito version 1.10.19. Will need to stick to this version.

Comment: Have never used `InjectMocks`. What's wrong with just writing `ABCDEF abcdef = new ABCDEF(helper, new URI("test"))` in the body of the test?

Comment: Either remove the ` = new ABCDEF(helper, new URI("test"))` and let mockito inject your mocks directly. OR remove `@InjectMocks` and add a method annotated with `@Before` where you instantiate `abcdef` yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ABCDEFTest {

    @Mock
    private Helper helper;

    private ABCDEF abcdef;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws URISyntaxException {
        abcdef = new ABCDEF(
                helper,
                new URI("test")
        );
    }


    @Test
    public void b() {
        abcdef.b();
    }
}
```

Or, instead of using `@RunWith`, you can initialize mock inside `setUp` method:

```
public class ABCDEFTest {

    private Helper helper;

    private ABCDEF abcdef;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws URISyntaxException {
        helper = Mockito.mock(Helper.class);
        abcdef = new ABCDEF(
                helper,
                new URI("test")
        );
    }


    @Test
    public void b() {
        abcdef.b();
    }
}
```